# Delete a has_many through relationship without an id in the link table

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, model, has-many

I would like to delete a relationship between the two models Project and Language. These two models are linked through a Link table which also stores extra parameters (is_default, ...)

My models are

```
class Project < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :links
    has_many :languages, :through => :links
    # ...
end
class Link < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :project
    belongs_to :language
end
class Language < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :links
    has_many :projects, :through => :links
    # ...
end
```

I tried this in Project controller :

```
 # Removes a languages associated to a project (links table)
  def remove_language
    lang = current_project.links.where("language_id = ?", params[:id])
    current_project.links.delete(lang) if lang

    redirect_to project_path(current_project), notice: 'Language has been removed from project.' 
  end
```

But I get the following error :

```
ActiveRecord::UnknownPrimaryKey in ProjectsController#remove_language
Unknown primary key for table links in model Link.
```

My routes.rb contains

```
resources :projects
match 'projects/remove_language/:id' => 'projects#remove_language'
match 'projects/add_language/:id' => 'projects#add_language'
```

I call my controller with this :

```
link_to "Remove", :controller => :projects, :action => :remove_language, :id => a.id
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
link = current_project.links.find_by_language_id(params[:id])
link.destroy
```

Comment: No, sorry, I get this error : ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid in ProjectsController#remove_language

SQLite3::SQLException: no such column: links.: DELETE FROM "links" WHERE "links"."" = ? 

It seems it looses the name of the column and the value... :-(